# Ajax loading close div after success

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello everyone Im using a small script that loads data and before it renders it shows a loading gif icon and then the table shows up, altho, I copied this from stack and I can't remember where, I noticed that at the end of the table when it renders at the end the gif div icon is still there D:

I have very low knowledge can anyone help me fix this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function cargar() {
        $('.button').on('click', function cargar() {
            //Añadimos la imagen de carga en el contenedor
            $('#divLoading').html('<div class="loading"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6viz.gif" alt="loading" /><br/>Un momento, por favor...</div>');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@comercial.Models.Base.DirectorioRaiz()PagosRecibidos/ConsultaPagosRecibidos',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    data: $("#formFiltros").serialize(),
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#divConsultaPagosRecibidos').html(response);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

## divLoading is still showing at the bottom of the screen :(

These are the divs where both gif and table render

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="divConsultaPagosRecibidos" style="width:100%">
        <!--aqui va el html de montos y tabla-->
    </div>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <div id="divLoading" style="width:100%"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: where did you hide it?

Comment: You're not doing anything with `#divLoading` in the response handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide the loader in success callback. 
You can use jQuery `hide()` for this. An example would be as below.

```
$('#divLoading').hide();
```

Read more about `hide()` in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/hide/).

The sample code is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function cargar() {
        $('.button').on('click', function cargar() {
            //Añadimos la imagen de carga en el contenedor
            $('#divLoading').html('<div class="loading"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6viz.gif" alt="loading" /><br/>Un momento, por favor...</div>');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@comercial.Models.Base.DirectorioRaiz()PagosRecibidos/ConsultaPagosRecibidos',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    data: $("#formFiltros").serialize(),
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#divConsultaPagosRecibidos').html(response);
                        $('#divLoading').hide();
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure whether creating a loader each time you click the button is a good idea. Rather, I would suggest you to show the loader on button click and hide it in success callback. Please remind to keep the loader hidden (preferably using css) on page load.

Comment: Thanks Sir as said in post I have very low experience in JS, altho I'll take my time to read the docs and take a class this weekend thanks a lot for the quick answer <3

Comment: Great...Go ahead..Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the success callback to hide the `$('#divLoading')` element before drawing the table

```
success: function (response) {
    $('#divLoading').hide();
    $('#divConsultaPagosRecibidos').html(response);
},
```